# Последовательность загрузки изображений React

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как ускорить загрузки изображений в проекте. 
Я из папки импортирую изображения с помощью `import image1 from './images/image1.jpg'`, затем в функции render() возвращаю `<Container><img src={image1} alt='image1'/></Container>`

Вопрос: когда я вижу контейнер и весь лейаут во время прогрузки изображения, но не вижу картинку, это значит, что:

- не прогрузился сам элемент img?
- находится на стадии `import image1 from ...`?
- что-то еще?

Где проблема и как ее решать? Хранить изображения в БД или как-то еще? Или есть аналог импорту какой-то, который работает быстрее?

Comment: эмммм, изображение в любом случае требует N времени, что бы загрузиться. То что вы прописали его в компоненте, не значит что браузер его мгновенно загрузит

Comment: если нужно, инлайнте изображение прямо в коде ( увеличит размер страницы )

Comment: @ThisMan мне тогда хотя бы как-нибудь сделать, чтобы не рендерился компонент, пока картинки не прогрузятся. Такое возможно? Чтобы не видно было этот контейнер, а вместо него там был спиннер, который изначально в <div id="root"></div>, например. А что имеется в виду под "инлайнить"?

Comment: И вообще, правильно ли так хранить изображения? В папке прям и импортировать?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет прямого отношения к React. React сам не занимается импортом, это работа сборщиков (напр-р, Webpack). Импорт ресурсов происходит во время сборки приложения (т.е. задолго до рендеринга), так что _находится на стадии import image1 from_ - вообще не в тему.

Comment: да, это нормальный подход, инлайнить, это значит вставлять через `base64`, если это не 4к картинки, конечно)

Comment: Картинки, к сожалению, правда большие, фотографии с зеркалки. Ну ладно, пока оставить так придется, наверное

Comment: @TimofeyMelentev Я ведь уже дал вам ответ касательно того, как можно не рендерить картинку в вашем предыдущем вопросе . Вам требуется так называемый `conditional rendering`. Базируясь на коде из моего ответа, можете добавить такой псевдокод в `render`:

 `<div>{
this.state.imageStatus === "loaded" ? 
<img
          src={this.props.imageUrl}
          onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}
          onError={this.handleImageErrored.bind(this)}
        /> : <div>Картинка еще грузится :)</div>
}
</div>`